# How to open a layout on change of the phone state?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

What i am trying to do is, at the end of the outgoing call and incoming call open a layout over the screen (only if the state changes to offhook in-between).
I want a layout to open up at the end whenever i answer an incoming call and whenever the other person attends my outgoing call.

Here is the code that i have written.

**MyPhoneStateHandler.java**

```
public class MyPhoneStateHandler extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            startSignalLevelListener();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();

            stopListening();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

            startSignalLevelListener();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stopListening();

            super.onDestroy();
        }

        private void stopListening(){
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(photoStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

        private void startSignalLevelListener(){
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            int event = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;

            tm.listen(photoStateListener, event);
        }

        private final PhoneStateListener photoStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                String callState = "UNKNOWN";
                int tmpstate = 0;
                switch(state)
                {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:      
                        callState = "IDLE";
                        if(tmpstate == 1){
                            setContentView(R.layout.cpl_after_call);
                            tmpstate = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:   
                        callState = "Ringing (" + incomingNumber + ")";
                        tmpstate = 1;
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:   
                        callState = "Offhook"; 
                        break;
                 }

                Log.i("CLApp", "onCallStateChanged " + callState);

                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
 }
```

I get a message during the call that the app have stopped functioning.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are looking to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect state transition when other person picks the call. Rest of the state transition will tell you if the call was dropped or not.

If  you want to detect if other person picked the call, you need to analyze and filterout the logs generated by Android. That is how a few app implement vibrate on call connect feature.